# crosstab pandas with condition on columns doesn't display summed values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, crosstab

I have a problem displaying what I want with pd.crosstab

I tried those lines:

```
pd.crosstab(df_temp['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).year), df_temp['state'][df_temp['state'] >= 20], margins=True])

pd.crosstab(df_temp['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).year), df_temp['state'][df_temp['state'] >= 20], margins=True, aggfunc = lambda x: x.count(), values = df_temp['state'][df_temp['state'] >= 20])
```

And they both display this:

```
state              20.0   30.0  32.0   50.0     All
date                                   
2017              303.0  327.0   6.0  118.0   754.0
2018              328.0  167.0   3.0   58.0   556.0
All               631.0  494.0   9.0  176.0  1310.0`
```

But what I want is not for each state to count the number of values being the state. For example for the state 20 for each year I want the value to be the count of all values greater or equal than 20. Thus it should be 754. For 30 it sould be 754 - 303 = 451. And so on for the other states.

I also tried this line of command but it doesn't work either:

```
pd.crosstab(df_temp['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).year), df_temp['state'][(df_temp['state'] >= 20)  | (df_temp['state'] == 30)], margins=True, aggfunc = lambda x: x.count(), values = df_temp['state'][(df_temp['state'] == 20) | (df_temp['state'] == 30)])
```

It displays the following table:

```
state              20.0   30.0  32.0  50.0     All
date                                  
2017              303.0  327.0   0.0   0.0   630.0
2018              328.0  167.0   0.0   0.0   495.0
All               631.0  494.0   NaN   NaN  1125.0
```

Comment: I finally did that : `idx = ["date"]
d = pd.melt(df_state, id_vars=idx)
pd.crosstab(d.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).year), d.variable, d.value, aggfunc="sum", rownames=idx, colnames=[None])` where df_state have 4 columns for each state

Comment: Do you have the input data available?  I'd recommend first filtering your dataframe down to just the relevant data, then use pd.crosstab on that filtered data, this keeps you from using complex lambda functions in aggfunc parameter.